Symfony make:entity No Longer Includes the Add Method, Why?
When I run bin/console make:entity in Symfony v6.4.6 it no longer makes add and remove methods in the new ServiceEntityRepository.  All of my previously generated repositories have those methods, and I'm not seeing any guidance about why this is different now.
Is there a new best practice?
I couldn't find any documentation about this change so far.

The real question is why were they added in the first place. The developer in charge of the Doctrine maker stuff is not super good at communicating and just does stuff. You can try checking the github issues or the Symfony github support. Who knows. The methods might just get added back.

The reason is based on this issue :
https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/1327
That led to this PR :
https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/pull/1328

Thank you.  I'm unable to edit this answer.  If you could block quote the "Flush should be done..." sentence from the issue page, I will accept!
